# How to use the same QAction in two QMenus with different text?

Tags: c++, qt

So I have an action I want to expose in multiple menus (one of the main menus, and some context menus). I'd like the menu item text to differ slightly from menu to menu (to make the mnemonic unique, and to be more or less verbose as necessary in each context).

In MFC (which I have the pleasure of migrating away from at the moment) this was easy, as each menu's items were defined separately, and could map to the same ID, which would be linked to the handler. In Qt though, the `QAction` encapsulates the behaviour as well as the text/icon/etc. So I don't suppose there's straightforward support for it to return a different text dependent on where it's being used.

My thought about how to handle this is, for each location, to create a "proxy" `QAction`, which has the text specific to that context and simply has its `triggered()` signal connected to the original `QAction`'s one. But I thought I should check first about whether there's an easier way to approach this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about MFC, but in Qt - QAction is just an interface. One QAction object can have only one text to display. But the real action QAction does, you will implement in what Qt calls SLOT. Then you can have as much interfaces(or QActions objects) pointing to the same slot - just connect all QAction objects, that you want to do the same thing, to the same slot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right, thank you, that makes sense. I hadn't looked at it that way because where I'm working the established technique is to subclass QAction and actually do the work (or some amount of it) in a slot on that class (connected to the signal on the same class).

Comment: Well if it's not a public slot, you can always connect a signal to a signal.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested solution is the simplest, I think. You can change the text of an action dynamically, when a menu is activated, but this looks more complicated to me.